# how to speed up pattern match between two files

Tags: regex, perl, awk

Input file1:

```
col1    col2    col3    col4
ZGLP1   ICAM4   13.27   0.2425
ICAM4   ZGLP1   13.27   0.2425
RRP1B   CDH24   20.8    1
ZGLP1   OOEP    18.79   0.3060
ZGLP1   RRP1B   39.62   0.2972
ZGLP1   CDH24   51.21   0.2560
BBCDI   DND1    19.44   0.2833
BBCDI   SOHLH2  36.61   0.2909
DND1    SOHLH2  18      0.8
```

Input file2:

```
chr8     18640000   18960000    ZGLP1   RRP1B   CDH24  #gene number here is not fixed can be #4 #5 or more
chr8     19000000   19080000    BBCDI   DND1    SOHLH2 #gene number here is not fixed can be #4 #5 or more
```

I have written a code which compares col1 and col2 of file1 with each line of file2 such that, if any of the pair falls anywhere in a line of file2 then programme should print "chromosome pos1 pos2 and the matching content of the file1 with values

output file:

```
chr8     18640000   18960000    ZGLP1   RRP1B 39.62 0.2972
chr8     18640000   18960000    ZGLP1 CDH24 51.21   0.2560
chr8     18640000   18960000    RRP1B CDH24 20.8    1
chr8     19000000   19080000    BBCDI   DND1 19.44  0.2833
chr8     19000000   19080000    BBCDI SOHLH2 36.61  0.2909
chr8     19000000   19080000    DND1 SOHLH2 18 0.8
```

so far I have tried this but it is taking so much time as my input files are huge (2gb).

my perl code

```
open( AB, "file1" ) || die("cannot open");
open( BC, "file2" ) || die("cannot open");
open( OUT, ">output.txt" );

@file = <AB>;

chomp(@file);
@data = <BC>;

chomp(@data);

foreach $fl (@file) {
    if ( $fl =~ /(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)/ ) {
        $one = $1;
        $two = $2;
        $thr = $3;
        $for = $4;
    }

    foreach $line (@data) {
        if ( $line =~ /(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*?)\s+(.*)+/ ) {
            $chr  = $1;
            $pos1 = $2;
            $pos2 = $3;
        }

        if ( $line =~ /$one/ ) {
            if ( $line =~ /$two/ ) {
                print OUT $chr, "\t", $pos1, "\t", $pos2, "\t", $fl, "\n";
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is your free memory > 2gb?

Comment: Currently your code is very slow because for every line of `file1`, it parses every line of `file2` to check for matches. You can speed this up immensely by parsing each file just once. I suggest you create an index hash using the data from one of the files and then consult that when you're parsing the data from the second file. Why don't you try to solve this problem yourself first, and then ask for help if you can't work it out?

Comment: yes, I am working on 16 gb ram system with >100 gb physical memory.

Comment: Benchmark regex vs split, use `index()` to match `$one` and `$two` strings. Do second matching/split right before `print OUT` and cache result if you have enough memory. And there is no need to read first file into array.

Comment: @ialarmedalien I am a beginner in perl so will you please elaborate how to use index hash in this case

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlfaq4.html gives a great basic intro to perl data structures, and I saw someone recommend http://qntm.org/files/perl/perl.html as a good tutorial for beginners. Work through the latter tutorial and it will teach you about hashes. I would make a hash of hashes with `$col1` as first key, `$col2` as the second key, and $col3+$col4 as the value, i.e. `$ix{$col1}{$col2} = $col3."\t".$col4` .

Comment: You don't need to hold both files in memory. So, parse the first file and create a hash as @ialarmedalien suggested. Then just read your second file one line at a time and do the lookups in the hash of file1, then discard the current line of file2 and read in and process the next line of file2.

Comment: I tried $ix{$col1}{$col2} = $col3."\t".$col4. But, I am not able to access two keys in foreach loop can you please modify the code. It will be really helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ cat tst.awk               
NR==FNR {
    if (NR>1)
        file1[$1,$2] = $0
    next
}
{
    for (i=3; i<=NF; i++)
        for (j=3; j<=NF; j++)
            if ( ($i,$j) in file1 )
                print $1, $2, $3, file1[$i,$j]
}
$ 
$ awk -f tst.awk file1 file2
chr8 18640000 18960000 ZGLP1   RRP1B   39.62   0.2972
chr8 18640000 18960000 ZGLP1   CDH24   51.21   0.2560
chr8 18640000 18960000 RRP1B   CDH24   20.8    1
chr8 19000000 19080000 BBCDI   DND1    19.44   0.2833
chr8 19000000 19080000 BBCDI   SOHLH2  36.61   0.2909
chr8 19000000 19080000 DND1    SOHLH2  18      0.8
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for the awk solution but this is not my desired solution.  `ZGLP1   ICAM4   13.27   0.2425` would not come because in `input file 2` `ZGLP1  RRP1B and CDH24` are together. so the program has to check for only those pairs as listed in output file

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. I mean to say  If any of the gene pairs of file 1 occur in the same line of file 2 then only i want to print. `chr8     18640000   18960000    ZGLP1   RRP1B   CDH24` doesn't have `ICAM4` in the same line.

Comment: ya Its gene pairs. Also sorry for not giving proper input files. As I edited now my `inputfile2` can contain more than 3 genes in the same line.  I have noticed in your code. I guess it been considered that gene number is fixed.

Answer (score 1):

A few ways to speed up your code:

Read in and parse file 1 first and create an index:

```
my %ix;
while (<AB>) {
    # skip the first line (with the column headers)
    next if $. == 1;
    chomp;
    # assuming that the data is tab-separated; if not, you can run split /\s+/
    my @arr = split "\t";
    # create a hash with structure $ix{col1}{col2} = "col3  col4"
    $ix{ $arr[0] }{ $arr[1] } = $arr[2] . "\t" . $arr[3];
}
```

Now read in file 2, one line at a time, and look for matches:

```
while (<BC>) {
    chomp;
    # initialise a set of variables all at once
    # assumes the data is tab-delimited; if it isn't, use split /\s+/
    my ($chr, $pos1, $pos2, $g1, $g2, $g3) = split "\t";

    # $g1, $g2, and $g3 are the three IDs on the line. This code assumes they will
    # always be in the order that they appear in file 1.
    # look for $g1 in our index. if ( $ix{$g1} ) is shorthand for checking if a
    # variable is defined and is non-zero.
    if ( $ix{$g1} ) {
        # now, for each of $g2 and $g3
        foreach my $g ($g2, $g3) {
            # ... check whether we've got an index entry where it is the second key
            if ( $ix{$g1}{$g} ) {
                # print out the data joined by tabs
                print OUT join("\t", $chr, $pos1, $pos2, $g1, $g, $ix{$g1}{$g}) . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
    # do the same check for $g2 and $g3. We have to check whether $ix{$g2} exists
    # first as if we check $ix{$g2}{$g3} directly and $ix{$g2} DOESN'T exist,
    # Perl will create it. This is known as autovivification.
    if ($ix{$g2} && $ix{$g2}{$g3}) {
        print OUT join("\t", $chr, $pos1, $pos2, $g2, $g3, $ix{$g2}{$g3}) . "\n";
    }
}
```